# Rails 5, Swagger UI not generating documentation json files for controllers

Tags: swagger, ruby-on-rails-5, swagger-ui

I was following [this Swagger tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/do-the-right-thing-and-document-your-rails-api-with-swagger/) to get familiar with the swagger environment and API documenting. I looked all the related issues on the [sample app's repo](https://github.com/richhollis/swagger-docs/issues) but none of them worked for me.

When I run `rake swagger:docs` it's supposed to generate `users.json` file under `public/api/v1/` hovewer it doesn't. It only generates `api-docs.json` file.
Also in the terminal gives the message `1.0: 0 processed / 4 skipped`.

I tried adding `Swagger::Docs::Config.base_api_controller = ActionController::API` which did not solved the issue either.

Sharing the basic files. If you need any further informations I will gladly share them with you. Hope you can help, really stuck here. Thank you.

**`swagger_docs.rb`**

```
# config/initializers/swagger-docs.rb
Swagger::Docs::Config.base_api_controller = ActionController::API

Swagger::Docs::Config.register_apis({
  "1.0" => {
    :api_file_path => "public/",
    :base_path => "http://localhost:3000",
    :clean_directory => true,
    :base_api_controller => ActionController::API,
    :attributes => {
      :info => {
        "title" => "Swagger Doc",
        "description" => "Sample app shows how to setup swagger for your Ruby APIs",
        "contact" => "recepinancc@gmail.com",
        "license" => "Apache 2.0",
        "licenseUrl" => "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**`users_controller.rb`**

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  swagger_controller :users, "User Management"

# /api/v1/users create documentation
  swagger_api :create do
    summary "To create user"
    notes "Implementation notes, such as required params, example queries for apis are written here."
    param :form, "user[name]", :string, :required, "Name of user"
    param :form, "user[age]", :integer, :optional, "Age of user"
    param_list :form, "user[status]", :string, :required, "Status of user, can be active or inactive"
    response :success
    response :unprocessable_entity
    response :500, "Internal Error"
  end

  # POST /api/v1/users
  def create
    ...
  end
...
end
```

And here's the only generated **`api-docs.json`**

```
{
  "apiVersion": "1.0",
  "swaggerVersion": "1.2",
  "basePath": "http://localhost:3000",
  "apis": [

  ],
  "authorizations": null,
  "info": {
    "title": "Swagger Doc",
    "description": "Sample app shows how to setup swagger for your Ruby APIs",
    "contact": "recepinancc@gmail.com",
    "license": "Apache 2.0",
    "licenseUrl": "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have find the solution to my problem comparing a running application to mine. And the only difference was the `routes.rb` file. Apparently I and Rails are skipped the step generating the nested route for our user model in routes.rb. After I added below to routes.rb problem solved.

```
namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users
    end
end
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `swagger_docs.rb`

```
include Swagger::Docs::ImpotentMethods

# Swagger::Docs::Config.register_apis({})

class Swagger::Docs::Config
  def self.base_api_controller
    ActionController::API 
  end
end
```

Or putting this at top of `routes.rb`

```
Swagger::Docs::Config.base_api_controller = ActionController::API
include Swagger::Docs::ImpotentMethods
```